# Find the error in the sentence

Tags: phrase-choice

Find the letter that corresponds with a sentence error in the below:

(A) I take great pleasure

(B) to welcome you

(C) to this institution.

(D) No error.

I think the error is in (B), and would change it to *in welcoming you*. Some books says there is no error. What is correct?

Comment: Your question has been edited a couple of times for clarity now. Please review it to make sure that it reads as you'd intended it to.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed "to welcome you" (b).

> I take great pleasure in welcoming you.

is a correct sentence ([see here for example](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=079cW7nDI4qhsgGto6T4Cw&q=%22I%20take%20great%20pleasure%20in%20welcoming%20you%22&oq=%22I%20take%20great%20pleasure%20in%20welcoming%20you%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...61809.65444.0.65622.17.17.0.0.0.0.156.1747.9j8.17.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.3.358...0j35i39k1j0i30k1j0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.Y2e9_N9e5hE)) and the correct choice out of the other choices there. But anyway I'm not sure how this sentence is common in the spoken English language.